# XML with adview, webview and search input in front of webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a webview with an adview on the top of it. I also have a search icon in the menubar, when user clicks on it, I show the search field to the user.

The problem is, the search field is not showing, I think it is covered by the webview.

So I'd like to have this:

[image]

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Close" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/closeButton"
            android:text="Next" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/findBox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nextButton"
            android:hint="Enter search keyword here."
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

why I can't see the search layout, how to build it as I'd like to?

Answer (score 1):

First, the layout where you have your search input is not visible (`android:visibility=GONE`).

Second, it's positioned bellow the WebView and not above as you want.

This should fix your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/closeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Close"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/closeButton"
                android:text="Next"/>

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/findBox"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nextButton"
                android:hint="Enter search keyword here."
                android:singleLine="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/webView1"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I set it to visible in my code, when user clicks on the search icon. most of the time it is invisible. I'll try it, thanks!!!